# Is any drag and drop facility in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I am new to BlackBerry. I have experience on Android. Now I want to learn BlackBerry. In Android an application contains res folder in that we add the layout in XML form and we can create the forms easily using views and layouts.

In the same way, is there any facility in BlackBerry? How do I prepare forms in BlackBerry?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about third party tools/packages, but I know there are no first party tools for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there doesn't exist any 3rd party tool or what you mention in Android. You 
must write all from code. Sure you can add layout, etc., but all from code.

Good luck with BlackBerry development :D Just a good idea: learn the MVC pattern very fast if you don't know yet because it helps very much at BlackBerry development (separate the model, view, controller classes and functionalities.)